# Match collections with their IDs from Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my DB I have different collections that can be tied up with their `ID's` so i can display some `event(s)`. But there's **one** collection that I can't seem to match up with the other collections.

One collection is called **events** and each event contains an attribute of `unit`:

[image]

And I also have a collection with `locks`(units) that contains the same `ObjectId`:

[image]
So my goal here is to being able to match a `lock`(unit) to the correct event(s). In my React and Redux app I have a route where I want to display the correct event(s) to the correct `lock`(unit). In my router I have this:

```
<AuthRoute path="/log/:lockId" component={LockDetails} />
```

And then in my parent that is supposed to display the list I have this:

```
class LockDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const lockId = this.props.match.params.lockId // Getting the ID from endpoint
    const locks = this.props.locks || [] // All locks(units) from Redux store
    const lock = locks.find(lock => { // Getting the correct lock form my params
      return lock._id === lockId 
    })
```

And then passing it down:

```
<LockLog lock={lock}/>
```

But here's where it get tricky. I wonder how I should write the code to get get the correct event(s) to the correct `lock`(unit).

When getting the `lock` from the parent I'm also using `keyBy` from the `lodash` library.

```
const keyedLocks = keyBy(lock, '_id')

const mappedEvents =
  events.reverse().map((event, i) => {
    var driver = event.driver ? keyedDrivers[event.driver] : false
    var carrier = driver ? keyedCarriers[driver.carrier] : false
    var customer = event.customer ? keyedCustomers[event.customer] : false
    var lock = event.unit ? keyedLocks[event.unit] : false // Tried something here, but it didn't go so well....

    return (
      <div>
        <EventItem
          key={i}
          event={event}
          customer={customer}
          carrier={carrier}
          driver={driver}
          lock={keyedLocks[event.unit] || { address: {} }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
```

This goes well with matching the data from my other endpoints to my `lock`(unit), but not with the event(s). So I would like some help since the only thing that gets outputted is this:

[image]

So no `lock`(unit) after *"öppnade på"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap lock into an array or object like: `const keyedLocks = keyBy([lock], '_id')`